# Styling cells in table with react-bootstrap components

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-component, react-table

I'm rendering a table in which each cell corresponds to a Button component of react-bootstrap.

```
<>
        <Table borderless className='below-nav table-style' responsive="sm">
            
            <tbody>
                {Array.from({ length: rows }).map((_, row_index) => (
                    <tr key={row_index}>
                        {Array.from({ length: columns }).map((_, column_index) => (
                            <Button className="td-style button-style"  variant="warning">
                            <td  key={column_index}>
                                ciao
                            </td>
                            </Button>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    </>
```

The problem is that it renders buttons that are not fulfilled with the color selected: `variant="warning"`, but just the border is of that color. There is another issue: bottom-border of each cell is not rendered at all so it seems clearly that something is overlayed on something else but i don't know why.

CSS like this seems not to work:

```
.table-style {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1px ;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.td-style {
  margin: 5px ;
}
```

Comment: Share the code of these classes `below-nav table-style`

Comment: Why do you wrap the `<td>` with the `<Button>`?

Comment: Remove `borderless` to show the bottom border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping the `<td>` with the `<Button>`, this is not the correct way to use a table. This is how it should work:

```
<>
        <Table responsive="sm">
            
            <tbody>
                {Array.from({ length: rows }).map((_, row_index) => (
                    <tr key={row_index}>
                        {Array.from({ length: columns }).map((_, column_index) => (
                            <td  key={column_index}>
                              <Button variant="warning">
                                ciao
                              </Button>
                            </td>
                            
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    </>
```

Basic DEMO of a table https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-knuth-qhpuu?file=/src/App.js